# NHibernate query against nested class

Tags: nhibernate, nested-class

I'm using NHibernate.  I have a class which has a nested type.  Is there any way, using NHibernate, to query against the nested type, asides from using a native SQL query?

[Nested classes are not allowed in HQL currently](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-285).

EDIT: The outer class has an IList of nested class instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done currently.

Answer (score 1):

Use a component mapping.

More information @ [NHibernate nested class mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588591/nhibernate-nested-class-mapping-problem)

Then, using HQL or Linq to NHibernate, you would simple say something like
string hql = "from Store s where s.Employee.Id = 3";

Comment: That won't work for me, unless a component can be mapped as a collection - the outer class contains an IList of nested class instances.